# fix footer at bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

When I try to fix the footer to the bottom as

```
#footer{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
```

I fix the footer at bottom but always keep in screen, how can I fixed at bottom of the content and make it adjustable to size of content?

Comment: I'm not sure which content you want to adjust it by. Can you post a more complete example?

Comment: this is css 101 stuff

Comment: you've been long enough on Stack to know how to mark questions with solutions as solved and you have many

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` is relative to the window. You will need to change it to `position: absolute` inside a container div that has `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

if you want show the content and footer on the window same time, you can use **`overflow-y:scroll`** and you can fix the footer on the bottom of page using `**position:fixed;**`

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;height:100%;
  }
div{
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  height:80%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  }
footer{
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:yellow;
  height:20%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="content">
afsal khan added user andaman naveen on Nov 21st U added user afsal khan on Nov 7th D deleted User afsal on Nov 7th U added user afsal on Friday U added user afsal on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Flatkit' on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Elite Green' on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Elite Blue' on Thursday U afsal khan added user dsaaa on Tuesday U added user afsal khan on Oct 28th more afsal khan added user andaman naveen on Nov 21st U added user afsal khan on Nov 7th D deleted User afsal on Nov 7th U added user afsal on Friday U added user afsal on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Flatkit' on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Elite Green' on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Elite Blue' on Thursday U afsal khan added user dsaaa on Tuesday U added user afsal khan on Oct 28th more afsal khan added user andaman naveen on Nov 21st U added user afsal khan on Nov 7th D deleted User afsal on Nov 7th U added user afsal on Friday U added user afsal on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Flatkit' on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Elite Green' on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Elite Blue' on Thursday U afsal khan added user dsaaa on Tuesday U added user afsal khan on Oct 28th more 
  afsal khan added user andaman naveen on Nov 21st U added user afsal khan on Nov 7th D deleted User afsal on Nov 7th U added user afsal on Friday U added user afsal on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Flatkit' on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Elite Green' on Thursday L afsal khan added a new Template 'Elite Blue' on Thursday U afsal khan added user dsaaa on Tuesday U added user afsal khan on Oct 28th more 

</div>
<footer>footer here</footer>
```